# О слове «артистический»

Tags: лексика, заимствования

Художественный руководитель (худрук) в начале 90-х почти был вытеснен арт-директором. Теперь вот в прошлом *art* расшифровали, и на ТВ зазвучало новое из старого: *артистический директор* и *артистический руководитель*. Насколько это правомерно и необходимо делать?

(Кстати, в словарях такой связки не наблюдается. Артистический — *талант, полный артистизма; художественный, утончённый, виртуозный, актерский, мастерский, мастерской, грамотный, ловкий, искусный, умелый*. Артистическая — *деятельность, карьера, внешность, натура, проделка, подделка, уборная, попойка, драка*. Артистическое — *исполнение, вышивание, кафе*.)

Answer (score 1):

**Артистический директор** (art director) —  это более  универсальное понятие, а также более удобное для понимания при переводе на западные языки.

Термин "художественный руководитель" с теми же функциями относился к театру, киностудии,  а в настоящее время **появилась необходимость художественного руководства в различных сферах жизни** (издательское дело, реклама и др.).

[art director | academic.ru](http://universal_en_ru.academic.ru/471002/art_director)
**Что такое art director?**

1) Общая лексика: главный художник (журнала, рекламного агентства), заведующий отделом иллюстраций, кино художник фильма, художественный руководитель (театра, киностудии), худрук, арт-директор

2) Техника: художественный редактор, художник фильма, художник-декоратор, художник-постановщик

3) Реклама: заведующий отделом художественного оформления (в рекламном агентстве), художник, художник-постановщик (фильма)

4) Патенты: ведущий художник

5) Деловая лексика: руководитель отдела художественного оформления рекламы (AD)

6) Макаров: художник фильма (кино), художник-постановщик (кино)

**Примеры:**

Я, так сказать, лицо фестиваля, его **артистический директор**, а Гога президент и главный организатор. [Юрий Башмет. Вокзал мечты (2003)]

Но присматривались к моей персоне очень долго, следили, как я отношусь к Наташе: не очень ли ей докучаю, не зажимаю ли ее как **артистический директор**. [Наталья Бестемьянова и др. Пара, в которой трое (2000-2001)]

Comment: Арт-директор пришёл к нам с Запада, и в переводе копии вроде нет нужды, да и не об том речь.  Вопрос — о слове «артистический»: почему этим словом заменили прижившееся у нас краткое деловое «art»? Почему, к примеру, не покушаются на арт-нуво?

Comment: Может быть, и прижившееся,  и деловое, но слишком на иностранный манер, в заимствовании   слов тоже меру надо знать. Кстати, арт… - первая часть сложных слов (сокр.: артиллерийский), пишется слитно, арт-… – первая часть сложных слов в знач. «художественный, относящийся к искусству», пишется через дефис. Кстати, об арт-нуво. Как пишется стиль: Арт Нуво, ар-нуво?..Ответ справочной службы русского языка: ар-нуво, нескл.

Comment: Слова с АРТ: арт-проект, арт-салон, арт-кафе, арт-рынок - не всегда вписываются в деловую речь. Арт-директор можно применять в разговорном (кратком)  варианте, а артистический директор - это в большей степени официальные название.